# In Postgresql, how do I debug an error that happens after a delete cascades?

Tags: debugging, postgresql, cascade

I'm deleting this row from a table and it has a bunch of cascades on the FKs and eventually it gives me this error:

> ERROR: insert or update on table "foo_route" violates foreign key constraint "foo_route_bar_fk"
>
> SQL state: 23503
>
> Detail: Key (bar_key)=(2176) is not present in table "bar".

foo_route_bar_fk is defined like this:

```
ALTER TABLE foo_route  
ADD CONSTRAINT foo_route_bar_fk FOREIGN KEY (bar_key) REFERENCES bar (bar_key) 
MATCH SIMPLE ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

I'm getting this error by deleting a table unrelated to both of these.  I think what's happening is a trigger or a cascade is causing this error, but it's difficult to find out why.

My question is, how do you debug issues like this in postgresql?  **What are the series of steps that caused this error?**  Postgresql only tells me the result of the last thing it did before it failed.  If this were code the error would give an extremely helpful stack trace.  Is there a way to see something like that in Postgresql?

Comment: You should find more details in the server log.  I suspect what you show above is what your client prints as error message.

Comment: @PeterEisentraut Yes that's correct, it's from the client.  I'll take a look in the server.log.  Is there any useful logging in there that's off by default?

Comment: The stuff that's relevant to this should be on by default. But a lot of other useful stuff isn't.

Comment: This doesn't get to the heart of your question, but might help with the actually situation that prompted you to ask. A little experimenting on SQL Fiddle reveals that Postgres *does* give distinct messages for the case where modifying the referenced table generates a constraint violation, and the one where modifying the referencing table does. If your delete were somehow not cascading and causing the violation, you'd see `ERROR: update or delete on table "bar" violates foreign key constraint "foo_route_bar_fk" on table "foo_route"`.

Comment: I think this means that you can be fairly sure that the cause of your problem *really is* an `INSERT` or `UPDATE` of "foo_route", which means it must be being caused by a trigger. I don't know how complicated your database is, but unless it's some crazy massive beast, I would guess you don't have many triggers that `INSERT INTO` or `UPDATE` "foo_route"? Can't you track down all the possible sources of the `INSERT` or `UPDATE`, and work backwards from there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically your postgresql log will include the statement which triggered the error.    That should allow you to follow the chains of cascading events.

One thing I would suggest however is that you might want to draw out a map of fkeys and look at the mappings of ON events on foreign keys.  If it were me I would start with a schema only dump or pg_autodoc output, and go from there.  The obvious problem is that you have deletes cascading in cases where it can't so you need to take a look and rethink things here.

Comment: *"The obvious problem is that you have deletes cascading in cases where it can't"* - explain? I'm not aware of any circumstance that can cause an attempt to cascade a `DELETE` to fail, besides subsequently violating some other constraint. That doesn't seem to be the case here, though, both because if it were, we'd expect to see that other constraint in the error message, and also because the error message appearing here can only be caused by an `INSERT` or `UPDATE` affecting the *referencing* column, not an `UPDATE` or `DELETE` on the *referenced* one.

Comment: Ok, what is happening here from the description of your problem is: delete A cascades to deleting B, which fails because row C still references it.  (This is one reason why cascading deletes IMO are rarely useful, because they add this sort of complexity to the application).

Comment: But we know that's *not what's happening* here, for the reasons I just gave. We know from the error message that an `INSERT` or `UPDATE` on a *referencing* column is what's triggering this, and we also know that if it *were* a delete from the referenced column triggering it, it ought to cascade, not error. An aside: in the scenario you described, as long as the key pointing from C to B is set to `ON DELETE CASCADE`, everything will cascade through. The problem you've described only comes about if you have some constraints in a constraint chain set to cascade, and others not.

Comment: An insert can't possibly trigger this so it has to be a delete or an update (keep in mind that under MVCC rules an update is basically a delete followed by an insert, postponing fkey checks until after the insert).  So in that case you update a unique value in table A, which cascades to a row in table B, but that row can't be changed because of a reference in table C.  The referencing update is what we are talking about.  Again the complexity that comes with this is one reason I save on delete and on update events for rare circumstances (I think LedgerSMB uses them about 3 times).

Comment: In case you are misunderstanding me.  Walking through this one step at a time.  Update or delete to row A on table A.  table B has an on update cascade on delete cascade fkey against table A so this cascades to the referencing column on table B.  This fails because table C is referencing the same column in table B causing a referential integrity failure.

Comment: I understand you fine, and indeed before I posted I'd considered the same explanation, but it's wrong. There's no way that the error message the OP is seeing could be triggered by the sequence of events that you suggest. Observe here - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/fc0b3/1 - different error message, so not the question asker's problem. Also, notice that a) it doesn't matter which Postgres version you use, the behaviour is the same, and b) adding in an "ON DELETE CASCADE" to the foreign key definition in table C solves the problem.

Comment: Ok so this suggests that if this is an cascading fkey, this can only be occurring from an update.  (Inserts can't cascade, and if we take the poster at his word that this is not being directly hit by the queries that leaves updates.)  But same problem, just update/key not existing yet (because not cascading), rather than delete/key not existing anymore (because not cascading).

Comment: (Also not sure if the error message may be different in what version of Pg the poster is using since this is not stated.)

Comment: I'm not convinced this is a `CASCADE` problem. A trigger seems more likely. You really have to try pretty hard to construct a schema weird or broken enough to produce the OP's error via cascades alone; indeed, I wasn't even sure it was possible until I managed it just now. Here is the example I managed to hack together:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/c8a8e/1

Basically, you need to have a column that directly references two or more other columns in order for this to happen. I've never seen that in a real database anywhere, and can't come up with a use case off the top of my head.

Comment: You might be right, but if the on delete cascade cases are not immediately obvious, I would be suspicious that the database might have all kinds of unpleasant surprises lurking in the dark corners.

Comment: In fact it occurs to me that this sort of error could easily creep into a db schema if the same foreign key was accidently created twice, once with cascading and once without.